# What is limitation of Pauli exclusion principle?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

According to Pauli "no two electrons in an atom can have the same values for all the four quantum numbers" but if we take any atom with $n=2$ and its 2<sup>nd</sup> subshell i.e 2p(that contain 3 orbitals) contains 6 electrons out of which 3 have the same spin direction i.e. clockwise and other 3 have anti clockwise spin - then doesn't this imply that three electrons can have the same values for all four quantum numbers - violating the Pauli law?

Comment: What are the four quantum numbers - and what makes you say they are all the same? Count them... are you sure there are 6 electrons in the 2P orbital?

Comment: The four quantum no are principal,azimuthal,magnetic and spin quantum no. And they r not same.

Comment: Read the que again . I  edit the que.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A $2p$ orbital has Principal quantum number $n=2$ and Orbital quantum number $l=1$. The Magnetic quantum number $m_l$ can take on three values of $-1,0,+1$. Each of the latter values corresponds to one sub-orbital, usually called $2p_x$, $2p_y$ and $2p_z$. Each sub-orbital of $2p$ can house 2 electrons, one with Spin quantum number $m_s$ of $+\frac12$  and one with $-\frac12$.

A *full* $2p$ orbital therefore 'contains' 6 electrons, two in each sub-orbital ($p_x, p_y, p_z$), *each electron* with a unique $n, l, m_l, m_s$ combination. Pauli's Exclusion Principle is perfectly respected.

[Further reading on electron configurations of atoms](http://www.chemteam.info/Electrons/QuantumNumbers-H-to-Ne.html).